# How to Insert Dependency Injection in mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I have Added Unit Testing in Existing MVC project and also added references

when i create object of controller

it throws an Exception due to DBContext context object i created in MVC but I need to do Dependency Injection and mocking so that it will not check for it.

please how can i make interface of db to do dependency injection.

code in mvc

```
public class TestingController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Testing/

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string uName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            QuestionsViewModel vm = new QuestionsViewModel();
            List<AddQuestion> adlist = new List<AddQuestion>();
            List<QuestionsViewModel> qlist = new List<QuestionsViewModel>();
            List<int> rn = new List<int>();
            List<int> rn2 = new List<int>();
            List<int> rn3 = new List<int>();
            AddQuestion adq = new AddQuestion();
            var Sessionid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            vm.sessionid = Sessionid.ToString();
            Session["ApplicantSession"] = Sessionid.ToString();

            ViewBag.StartTime = Session.Timeout;


            List<List<int>> threecompQids = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> c1question = db.AddQuestions.Where(x => x.ComplexityLevel == 1)
                .Select(y => y.AddQuestionID).ToList();
            List<int> c2question = db.AddQuestions.Where(x => x.ComplexityLevel == 2)
                .Select(y => y.AddQuestionID).ToList();
            List<int> c3question = db.AddQuestions.Where(x => x.ComplexityLevel == 3)
              .Select(y => y.AddQuestionID).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int r = rnd.Next(c1question.Min(), c1question.Max() + 1);
                while (!(c1question.Any(w => w.Equals(r)) && !rn.Any(w => w == r)))
                {
                    r = rnd.Next(c1question.Min(), c1question.Max() + 1);
                }
                rn.Add(r);
                r = rnd.Next(c2question.Min(), c2question.Max() + 1);
                while (!(c2question.Any(w => w.Equals(r)) && !rn2.Any(w => w == r)))
                {
                    r = rnd.Next(c2question.Min(), c2question.Max() + 1);
                }
                rn2.Add(r);
                r = rnd.Next(c3question.Min(), c3question.Max() + 1);
                while (!(c3question.Any(w => w.Equals(r)) && !rn3.Any(w => w == r)))
                {
                    r = rnd.Next(c3question.Min(), c3question.Max() + 1);
                }
                rn3.Add(r);

            }



            var fstquestion = rn[0];
            threecompQids.Add(rn);
            threecompQids.Add(rn2);
            threecompQids.Add(rn3);

            vm.ComplexLevQidsLists = threecompQids;

            adq = db.AddQuestions.Find(fstquestion);
            List<Option> opt = db.Options.Where(op => op.AddQuestionID == adq.AddQuestionID).ToList();
            vm.Questions = adq;
            vm.Options = opt;
            vm.UserName = uName;

            return View(vm);


        }

}
```

where as in test project i only created object of testcontroller

Comment: How are we supposed to understand the problem without any code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't mock data access component your controller depends on, right? If this is the case and you are using actual implementation in your unit test, most likely your connection string defined in `Test` project is missing or differs from the connection string defined in `MVC` project.

Also keep in mind that if you do not mock your controller's dependencies, your unit test is technically cannot be considered as "unit" — it's more like an integration or scenario test.

Comment: please tell me how to mock data access component and what references should be added in my test project

Comment: Nsubstitute is a great mocking/sub library.  Their is a nuget package that you can add in your test project that includes everything you need.  See the documentation here for more specifics: http://nsubstitute.github.io/

Comment: i installed it in my project what are further steps please explain in detail

Comment: i did the installation of Moq

Comment: @SyedAnwarShahTarn Unfortunately, dependency injection and writing testable code are out of scope of this question (and it would take me a while to explain these topics). Just google something about DI principles, unit testing and Moq library (if you decided to use it). As I can see, my original suggestion was correct — your `ApplicationDbContext` was unable to initialize because of lack of the connection string in your `Test` project.

Comment: then what i have to do for this 
should i create connection string in test project or something else please do something

Comment: @SyedAnwarShahTarn yes, just add the connection string to your `Test` project, it should help.

Comment: but i don't kow how to add conn string in test project

Comment: @SyedAnwarShahTarn Add `app.config` file to your unit test project and copy connection string from the MVC project.

Comment: @Sergey I have done it but now i am getting different error 
An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: @SyedAnwarShahTarn well, that's a good sign — your original issue was fixed! :) Now you have to solve the next one, which is, again, out of scope of this question.

Comment: what is the second problem and please tell me what references i should add from mvc to test

Comment: hey the exception was, it was looking db in bin folder so i copied db from app folder of mvc project to bin of test now no error but test takes time to pass 3 - 4 sec is that good approach

Comment: Hey @SyedAnwarShahTarn, I guess you might be interested in this article I've recently wrote, because it strictly related to code testability topic you've been interested in: http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters

Answer (score 1):

You should either abstract the ApplicationDbContext using an interface like IAppDbContext or provide the connection string to the testing project too. In the latter case your test will stop being unit test though.

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    IAppDbContext _context;

    pulbic MyController(IAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context; // Now you can use the interface to perform your data access operations
    }

    ....
}
```

And now you will be able to inject mock implementations of IAppDbContext in your unit tests.

You should do some research on Dependency Inversion and Mocking.

Comment: could u please tell me what should be declared in IAppDbContext Interface and  which class should be inherited from it

Comment: i have implemented IAppDbContext but can u please tell me in Interface IAppDbContext what should be declared